# Horizontally Scaling Database Guide

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cluster-computing, sharding

We want to horizontally scale our existing MongoDB database which is running on one server. Due to increased user base, we can't scale it vertically anymore. We need to scale it horizontally through sharding.

The MongoDB provides a good [tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) to achieve Sharding. But, we need to do it in less amount of time. We are not expert on this.

It seems there are multiple options available like Google Cloud and Amazon RDS. All we want is to use our database but achieve Sharding by some another service.

So my questions are:
1. Is it possible to build a fail-safe cluster architecture is less than a week using MongoDB Sharding with the team having no prior experience in this?
2. If not, do these services like Google cloud SQL and Amazon RDS provide a mechanism to use our database with their Sharding service?

Can anyone with expertise in this just guide me in this direction?

Comment: cloud SQL and RDS are not mongodb. Sharding is not complex but you will need to learn it. Atlas allows sharding starting from M30 plans. It will help with maintenance but you still need to learn how to spread your data, i.e. define the [shard key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/)

Answer (score 1):

I tried MongoDB Atlas and it looks pretty good https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas

It creates a cluster for you by default

Maybe, you can give it a try:

> MongoDB Atlas delivers the world’s leading database for modern
>   applications as a fully automated cloud service engineered and run by
>   the same team that builds the database. Proven operational and
>   security practices are built in, automating time-consuming
>   administration tasks such as infrastructure provisioning, database
>   setup, ensuring availability, global distribution, backups, and more.
>   The easy-to-use UI and API let you spend more time building your
>   applications and less time managing your database.

Comment: Is the data stored on our server or theirs in case of MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: It is stored in their servers.

Comment: OP's question is about storing data in his server and using a third party clustering service.

Comment: @krupal.agile, are you sure OP asked about  "storing data in his server and using a third party clustering service."? Could you elaborate what is "clustering service" in this context then?

Comment: @AlexBlex 1.Yes. As written "do these services like Google cloud SQL and Amazon RDS provide a mechanism to use our database with their Sharding service?" 2. Something like MySQL cluster manager maybe....I don't know. https://www.mysql.com/products/

Comment: @krupal.agile The quoted sentence doesn't makes sense to me at the first place. I already commented on it in the question. Just repeating it doesn't make it any clearer. A UI to manage on-premises mongodb cluster was once called Cloud Manager. Now it is integrated into Atlas. It is an advanced tool that requires some experience in managing cluster manually.

Comment: @AlexBlex Ok. I have just one question: Is it easy to do sharding with MongoDB without using Atlas or Cluster Manager for someone having no prior expertise?

Comment: @krupal.agile define "easy". Such questions are considered offtopic since any possible answer will be based on personal opinion. I wouldn't risk established business by deploying any new technology to production with no experience in it. Instead I would learn and gain required skills. After all walking is a way more complex task yet most of 1 year olds manage to learn it without having prior experience. Mongodb isn't backed by 50+ years of scientific researches like SQL. It's all about learning and experimenting. Give it a try and decide whether it is "easy" to you or not.